# What is the order of creating and destroying main class and its superclass

Tags: java, class, constructor, destructor, java-compiler-api

Given that execution starts from main method how can super-class instance be created before main class instance and if given that super class must be initialized first before main class, will the Super-class of the main class be first destroyed or destroying main class first would harm the program if necessary?

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

       public static void main(String args[]){

                super("Title of my prog");       // Superclass method
                //code
                //code
            }

      }
```

Comment: Could you give code examples?

Comment: okay a rough code of my question...

Comment: If you have a class Sub and it's superclass Super, and you create an instance of Sub, that *does not* create a *separate* instance of Super.  Rather, the instance of Sub incorporates all of the features of an instance of Super, so it can do anything a Super instance can do.

Comment: (This has nothing really to do with the `main` method used to enter a Java program.  `static` methods need no instance to operate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `main` must be `static` is precisely so that the JVM doesn't have to construct an instance for the main class before it starts the program's execution, and it's quite common for a main class never to be instantiated.

Comment: will creation of instance of Superclass fail if main method is not declared as static or is there a substitute?

Comment: If the `main` method is not static, then it's not a valid entry point (it's just an ordinary method that happens to be called `main`). The static entry point *does not have* an instance of the superclass.

Comment: Not a Java expert but as I see the inhiritance it's not used with static methods, I mean, a static method can exist without any intance, so it doesn't have to worry about who's derivem from who